# How to refresh Display or Canvas of java me Midp 2.0?

Tags: canvas, java-me, refresh, nokia

I'm trying to get some picture on the screen anywhere in the cycle of just that I can not refresh Canvas. Нow can I do this? 
Here is an example code:

The question is how can refreshna canvas?

```
    class KeyCanvas extends Canvas {
        int x=50;int y=50;
        Image image = null;
        private Random rnd = new Random();

      public KeyCanvas() {
          for (int I=0; I<=5; I++){
                x = rnd.nextInt(146) + 1;
                y = rnd.nextInt(150) + 1;
                try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
            repaint();
            }  
      }

      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          try{image = Image.createImage("/ship01.JPG");
          }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();}
          g.drawImage(image, x, y, Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER);
         }

      protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
            System.out.println("keyPressed " +((char)keyCode));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by refresh.
Looking at your code, it should draw the image just fine.
If you are talking about clearing the canvas before drawing the image again, it is typically done this way:

```
g.setClip(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.setColor(0x000000); // Colour to clear with
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Another thing:
Don't load your image inside the `paint()` method.
Load it once outside your main loop. There's no need to reload it every time you want to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

First, mr_lou is right about loading image in paint(). First, it can be reused and should be reused for performance reasons, and second, it may be dangerous to use blocking I/O in a method called by the system (here paint()).

What looks very weird to me is that the animation (with sleep) is implemented in the constructor. I wonder how you make the canvas visible - the animation finishes before you can do it, or not? Next thing to check is whether you do not create the canvas instance from another callback (such as keyReleased etc), because it will likely block the event stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course I ignored it with IF in the case just before I gave an example of my problem was that he could not refresh paint among the changes I found a solution for it this way:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

public class pro extends MIDlet {
    Display display;
    Command exit;
    static int id=1;

    public pro() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    }
    public void destroyApp (boolean unconditional) {
    }
    public void pauseApp () {}
    public void startApp () {
       display = Display.getDisplay(this);

       Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
        int x;int y;
        Image image = null;
        Random rnd = new Random();

         public void paint(Graphics g) {

         if (id==1){id=2;
         try{image = Image.createImage("/ship01.JPG");
         }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();}}

         g.setColor(0x000000);
         g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
         x = rnd.nextInt(146) + 1;
         y = rnd.nextInt(150) + 1;

         g.drawImage(image, x, y, Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER);
         }

         protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
         System.out.println("keyPressed " +((char)keyCode));
         }
     }; // end of anonymous class

     display.setCurrent(canvas);

    for (int I=0; I<=5; I++){
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
    canvas.repaint();
    }

    }
}
```